# "==" command in within() function generates new variable?

Tags: r

Some codes to reproduce the problem:

```
data(iris)
print(iris)
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
               ...The rest is abbreviated...
```

#Do a loop, and use "==" to terminate it.

```
iris2=within(iris,{
  for(i in 1:150){
    if(i==123) break
  }
})

print(iris2)
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species   i
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa 123
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa 123
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa 123
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa 123
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa 123
                     ...abbreviated...
```

An additional column named i was shown, how come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for` loop creates a variable in the calling environment to do the counting. Variables assigned `within` the environment created from your data are added to that environment. Either put the `for` loop outside the `within` call, or set the value of `i` to `NULL` before exiting the `within` call, eg:

```
if(i==123) {i<-NULL;break}
```

Comment: Oh I see, I thought it was "==" assign 123 to i, turns out it is because the loop breaks at i==123. Thank you.

Comment: `==` is the equality comparison operator, `=` is one of the assignment operators.

Comment: Is there a reason that people use I<-NULL instead of rm(i)?

Comment: To James: I know that, that why this question puzzles me.

Comment: It is easier, in general, to remove variables from a data.frame by assigning NULL to the variable, but when using `within`, `rm` will work too.

Comment: To quote part of `?within`, "Evaluate an R expression in an environment constructed from data, possibly modifying the original data."  Not that it's crystal clear to folks new to `R` what happens.  Nicely written, James.